# Why are NAs included in a conditional subset if they don't meet the condition?

Tags: r

Say we create a vector like this:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 2, NA)
```

And we test it for a simple condition:

```
> v == 1
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

Subsetting the vector using this condition, we obtain this:

```
> v[v == 1]
[1]  1 NA
```

Why is the `NA` included in the subset when it clearly doesn't meet the condition? I'm aware that `NA == 1` returns `NA`, but why is the subsetting not taking `TRUE` values exclusively? What am I missing here?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49890440/12545041).

Comment: Also this post [Dealing with TRUE, FALSE, NA and NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822426/dealing-with-true-false-na-and-nan)

Comment: ```NA``` has no value, if you compare it with a value as you did with ```v == 1```, you can't get a ```TRUE``` or ```FALSE``` back. A non-value can't be compared to a value so R will return a ```NA```. The close reason and other linked questions in the comments explain it more thorough.

Comment: Wrong duplicate, SamR's suggestion would be the right one. Additionally, if you use, `subset()`, `dplyr::filter()`, or data.table, the NAs will be excluded (and not everybody likes that). "it clearly doesn't meet the condition" is not true here, the opposite is true, we can't say if it meets the condition or not.